# Using Arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

My question is:

- Is this code correct and is it properly assigned to the Wheel speeds and duration
- What do I need to do in order to add the main method to run the code
- use a for loop to iterate through each row, instructing the Finch robot to move according to the numbers in each row. Pause after each movement using the code JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Click OK to continue...");

public class FinchArray {

```
public static final int LEFT_WHEEL = 0;
public static final int RIGHT_WHEEL = 1;
public static final int DURATION = 2;{


    int[][] x = new int[10][3]; // 2D array filled with zeros
    int time = 25;
    for (int[] row : x) {
        row[2] = time;
        time += 25;
    }

    for (int[] row : x) {
        row[DURATION] = time;
        time += 25;
    }

    for (int[] row : x){
        row[LEFT_WHEEL] = time;
        time += 25;
    }

    for (int[] row : x){
        row[RIGHT_WHEEL] = time;
        time += 25;
    }

    Finch fRobot = new Finch();

    fRobot.setWheelVelocities(LEFT_WHEEL,RIGHT_WHEEL,DURATION);
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - before < 5000){

         if(fRobot.isObstacle())break; {

        }
            fRobot.stopWheels();
            fRobot.quit();

    }





}
```

Comment: What have you done so far to solve your problem? Have you written some code that you could post here?

Comment: What are you having trouble with? What have you tried?

Comment: You need to revise the way you're using your for-loop at `for(i = 0; i < 256;i = i + 25);` For-loops require `{}` after the conditions where you put your loop logic into it.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage - `for` loops do not require braces in cases where the body is a single statement. One of OP's problems (among many) is that the `for` loop is terminated by the semicolon at the end of the line. Another major problem is using `i` both as an index and as the time value. My guess is that OP is getting a nice `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when his code tries to assign a new 10-element array to `x[256]`.

Comment: I stand corrected -- but what you wrote is the jist I was trying to hint to him without explicitly telling him what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you for everything guys. One last thing is I need to run my code do I need to create a separate class with the main body method to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize your 2D array (which, in Java, is really just an array of 1D arrays) like this:

```
int[][] x = new int[10][3]; // 2D array filled with zeros
int time = 25;
for (int[] row : x) {
    row[2] = time;
    time += 25;
}
```

This uses an [*enhanced `for` loop*](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) and is equivalent to this:

```
int[][] x = new int[10][3]; // array filled with zeros
int time = 25;
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
    int[] row = x[i];
    row[2] = time;
    time += 25;
}
```

Note that this leaves the left and right wheel speeds at their default values of zero.

Your current code is first creating a 10x3 2D array, but then your loop is reassigning each row to be a new 10-element array, so you end up with a 10x10 array (which is not what you want).

P.S. Using a 3-element array to represent three distinct pieces of data is not a good programming style (although it will work just fine). A slight improvement can be obtained by using symbolic constants for the subscripts. Declare at the top of your class:

```
public static final int LEFT_WHEEL = 0;
public static final int RIGHT_WHEEL = 1;
public static final int DURATION = 2;
```

Then use these to index into each row:

```
for (int[] row : x) {
    row[DURATION] = time;
    time += 25;
}
```

Since each row represents three different attributes, a better approach would be to define a separate class to contains the data:

```
public class Step {
    public int leftWheelSpeed;
    public int rightWheelSpeed;
    public int duration;
}
```

Then instead of a 2D array of `int` values, you can declare a 1D array of `Step` objects:

```
Step[] x = new Step[10];
int time = 25;
for (Step step : x) {
    step.duration = time;
    time += 25;
}
```

Comment: The other problem I have now is how can I assign the values from 25 to 250 to the LEFT WHEEL, RIGHT WHEEL, and Duration then run these using the Finch Robot.

Comment: @user3351284 - The [docs](http://www.finchrobot.com/javadoc/edu/cmu/ri/createlab/terk/robot/finch/Finch.html) seem pretty straightforward: call `setWheelVelocities(int,int,int)` for each row. Use a [Swing timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to wait for the required time between calls.

Comment: What do I need to add to the public class Step? I really don't understand how to assign the arrays to the speeds and time.

Comment: @user3351284 - My sample code showed how to assign duration values starting at 25 and going up by 25 for each of the 10 steps. You could use similar logic for the wheel speeds. I'm having a hard time understanding what the difficulty is here.

Comment: One last thing I figured out how to do it but do I need to create a separate class for the code to run the Finch because I can't create a main method with the final ints I have assigned.

Comment: @user3351284 - I suggest that you mark this question as solved and post your current issue as a new question. When a single question keeps evolving, it becomes less useful to others on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but is this maybe what you are looking for?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FinchArray {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        int[][] array = new int[3][10]; // initializing the array

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // outer for loop loops over first dimension
            int n = 25; // initializing the counter from 25 to 250
            for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) { // inner for loop loops over second dimension
                array[i][j] = n; // access the slots with the two indices i and j and give them the value of n
                n += 25;
            }
            n = 25; // reset n to 25 after finishing the inner for loop
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
    }

}
```

Output: `[[25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250], [25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250], [25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250]]`